# Failed to import data to a stream table containing array vectors with DolphinDB Python API

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip, dolphindb

The following script defines a stream table where the column “askPrice“ and “bidPrice“ are array vectors of DOUBLE type.

```
share streamTable(
    10000:0, 
    `time`sym`askPrice`bidPrice, 
    [DATETIME,SYMBOL,DOUBLE[],DOUBLE[]]
    ) as testSt;
```

Script in Python:

```
import dolphindb as ddb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    se = ddb.session("localhost", 8848)
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "time": pd.Timestamp.now().to_numpy(),
            "sym": ["600519.SH"],
            "askPrice":[np.array([11.0,12.0],dtype=np.float64)], 
            "bidPrice":[np.array([11.1,12.1],dtype=np.float64)], 
        }
    )

    n = se.run("tableInsert{testSt}", df)
    print(n)
```

But an exception was thown when I run the script:

```
RuntimeError: <Exception> in call: Failed to append data to column 'askPrice'
```

I tried to change the data type of column askPrice and bidPrice with the following script, but it still failed:

```
import dolphindb as ddb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    se = ddb.session("localhost", 8848,"admin", "123456")

    values = np.array([np.array([11,12,13,14],dtype=np.float64)],dtype=object)

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "time": pd.Timestamp.now().to_numpy(),
            "sym": ["600519.SH"],
            "askPrice":values, 
            "bidPrice":values, 
            #"askPrice":[np.array([11.0,12.0],dtype=np.float64)], 
            #"bidPrice":[np.array([11.1,12.1],dtype=np.float64)], 
        }
    )

    n = se.run("tableInsert{testSt}", df)
```

Error message is as follows:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

The following is the version of related packages (in Windows environment):

```
PS C:\Users\demo> pip list
Package                            Version  
---------------------------------- ---------
alabaster                          0.7.12
anaconda-client                    1.7.2
anaconda-navigator                 1.9.7
anaconda-project                   0.8.3
asn1crypto                         1.0.1
astroid                            2.3.1
astropy                            3.2.1
atomicwrites                       1.3.0
attrs                              19.2.0
Babel                              2.7.0
backcall                           0.1.0
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.5
backports.os                       0.1.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.tempfile                 1.0
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4                     4.8.0
bitarray                           1.0.1
bkcharts                           0.2      
bleach                             3.1.0
bokeh                              1.3.4
boto                               2.49.0
Bottleneck                         1.2.1
certifi                            2019.9.11
cffi                               1.12.3
chardet                            3.0.4
Click                              7.0
cloudpickle                        1.2.2
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.4.1
comtypes                           1.1.7
conda                              4.7.12   
conda-build                        3.18.9
conda-package-handling             1.6.0
conda-verify                       3.4.2
contextlib2                        0.6.0
cryptography                       2.7
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.29.13
cytoolz                            0.10.0
dask                               2.5.2    
decorator                          4.4.0
defusedxml                         0.6.0
distributed                        2.5.2
docutils                           0.15.2
dolphindb                          1.30.19.4
entrypoints                        0.3
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.1.0
filelock                           3.0.12   
Flask                              1.1.1
fsspec                             0.5.2
future                             0.17.1
gevent                             1.4.0
glob2                              0.7
greenlet                           0.4.15
h5py                               2.9.0
HeapDict                           1.0.1
html5lib                           1.0.1
idna                               2.8      
imageio                            2.6.0
imagesize                          1.1.0
importlib-metadata                 0.23
ipykernel                          5.1.2
ipython                            7.8.0
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.5.1
isort                              4.3.21
itsdangerous                       1.1.0
jdcal                              1.4.1
jedi                               0.15.1   
Jinja2                             2.10.3
joblib                             0.13.2
json5                              0.8.5
jsonschema                         3.0.2
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     5.3.3
jupyter-console                    6.0.0
jupyter-core                       4.5.0
jupyterlab                         1.1.4    
jupyterlab-server                  1.0.6
keyring                            18.0.0
kiwisolver                         1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy                  1.4.2
libarchive-c                       2.8
llvmlite                           0.29.0
locket                             0.2.0
lxml                               4.4.1
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1    
matplotlib                         3.1.1
mccabe                             0.6.1
menuinst                           1.4.16
mistune                            0.8.4
mkl-fft                            1.0.14
mkl-random                         1.1.0
mkl-service                        2.3.0
mock                               3.0.5
more-itertools                     7.2.0
mpmath                             1.1.0    
msgpack                            0.6.1
multipledispatch                   0.6.0
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbconvert                          5.6.0
nbformat                           4.4.0
networkx                           2.3
nltk                               3.4.5
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           6.0.1
numba                              0.45.1   
numexpr                            2.7.0
numpy                              1.19.3
numpydoc                           0.9.1
olefile                            0.46
openpyxl                           3.0.0
packaging                          19.2
pandas                             0.25.1
pandocfilters                      1.4.2    
parso                              0.5.1
partd                              1.0.0
path.py                            12.0.1
pathlib2                           2.3.5
patsy                              0.5.1
pep8                               1.7.1
pickleshare                        0.7.5
Pillow                             6.2.0
pip                                19.2.3
pkginfo                            1.5.0.1  
pluggy                             0.13.0
ply                                3.11
prometheus-client                  0.7.1
prompt-toolkit                     2.0.10
psutil                             5.6.3
py                                 1.8.0
pycodestyle                        2.5.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.19
pycrypto                           2.6.1    
pycurl                             7.43.0.3
pyflakes                           2.1.1
Pygments                           2.4.2
pylint                             2.4.2
pyodbc                             4.0.27
pyOpenSSL                          19.0.0
pyparsing                          2.4.2
pyreadline                         2.1
pyrsistent                         0.15.4
PySocks                            1.7.1    
pytest                             5.2.1
pytest-arraydiff                   0.3
pytest-astropy                     0.5.0
pytest-doctestplus                 0.4.0
pytest-openfiles                   0.4.0
pytest-remotedata                  0.3.2
python-dateutil                    2.8.0
pytz                               2019.3
PyWavelets                         1.0.3
pywin32                            223
pywinpty                           0.5.5    
PyYAML                             5.1.2
pyzmq                              18.1.0
QtAwesome                          0.6.0
qtconsole                          4.5.5
QtPy                               1.9.0
requests                           2.22.0
rope                               0.14.0
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.46  
scikit-image                       0.15.0
scikit-learn                       0.21.3
scipy                              1.3.1
seaborn                            0.9.0
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
setuptools                         41.4.0
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
six                                1.12.0
snowballstemmer                    2.0.0
sortedcollections                  1.1.2    
sortedcontainers                   2.1.0
soupsieve                          1.9.3
Sphinx                             2.2.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.2    
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.3
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.1.2
spyder                             3.3.6
spyder-kernels                     0.5.2
SQLAlchemy                         1.3.9
statsmodels                        0.10.1
sympy                              1.4
tables                             3.5.2
tblib                              1.4.0    
terminado                          0.8.2
testpath                           0.4.2
toolz                              0.10.0
tornado                            6.0.3
tqdm                               4.36.1
traitlets                          4.3.3
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
urllib3                            1.24.2
wcwidth                            0.1.7    
webencodings                       0.5.1
Werkzeug                           0.16.0
wheel                              0.33.6
widgetsnbextension                 3.5.1
win-inet-pton                      1.1.0
win-unicode-console                0.5
wincertstore                       0.2
wrapt                              1.11.2   
xlrd                               1.2.0
XlsxWriter                         1.2.1
xlwings                            0.15.10
xlwt                               1.3.0
zict                               1.0.0
zipp                               0.6.0
```

Comment: Hi Claire, I could not reproduce your problem... I just ran the top 2 code blocks and everything worked well (DolphinDB Systems 2.00.7 64 bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by version incompatibility between python packages.

It is recommended to upgrade numpy to version 1.19.5, and pandas to version 1.3.5/1.1.0.

You can upgrade with the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy==1.21.5
pip install --upgrade pandas==1.3.5
```